# Get value of one span and insert in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one span element that I've hidden with CSS and that I need to get the value of. So I can add a span element inside another div. How can I do this with jQuery?

I start with

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $(".span-class").text();
}
```

I used this, but it didn't work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $(".span-class").text();
    $(".span-class").append($(".div-class").html());
});
```

What else can I do? Thanks!

**EDIT**:
This is what I need the HTML to look like after I run my jQuery:

From:

```
<div class="div-class"></div>
```

To:

```
<div class="div-class">
<span>/content of .span-class</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you have hidden your span element with your css, even if you append the span element in your div element because that span element is hidden, It will still not visible in your browser. if you whan your span élement to be visible you must first change the visibilité of that element `$('.span-class).css('display', 'block')` and after that it will be visible in your browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I can add a span element inside another div

You need the opposite, you need to append the `span` to the `div`, like :

```
$(".div-class").append( $(".span-class").html() );
```

If you want to add just the text of the span you could use `.text()` :

```
$(".div-class").append( $(".span-class").text() );
```

**Note :** If you need the whole tag not just the content you could use outerHTML like :

```
$(".span-class")[0].outerHTML
```

```js
$(".div-class").append( $(".span-class").html() );
```

```css
.span-class{
   display: none;
}

.div-class{
   background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="span-class">SPAN CONTENT</span>

<div class="div-class"> DIV CONTENT </div>
```

Comment: But how to add the value from that inside the div, but the value to be inside a span element, so i can move it around?

Comment: Check the snippet, and give me an example please.

Comment: That's it! Thank you, Zakaria!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, this should work:

```
var $spanClone = $('.span-class').clone()
$spanClone.removeClass('span-class')
$('.div-class').append($spanClone)
```

This method will clone the hidden `span`, remove the class that hides it, then append it to the `div`.